# HTML/PHP: How to create multiple radio buttons for each row in a table?

Tags: php, html, select, radio-button, name-attribute

I have an HTML table having n rows. Each row has a name and 3 radio buttons. What I want to do is, each row must have a selected radio button. However, when I choose a radio button in the first row and I choose another radio button in the second row, the first radio button becomes unselected. I know that the problem is with the name attribute of the radio button but I don't know how to fix it. What should I do? Thank you in advance.

Here's my code.

```
echo '<table>';
list($cols,) = $xlsx->dimension();
foreach( $xlsx->rows() as $k => $r) {
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$k.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$name.'</td>';
        echo '<td><Input type = "Radio" Name ="vote" value= "pacada"></td>';
        echo '<td><Input type = "Radio" Name ="vote" value= "toledo"></td>';
        echo '<td><Input type = "Radio" Name ="vote" value= "undecided1" checked></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable to the name:

```
$row = 0;
foreach(...) {
    $row++
    ...
    echo '<td><Input type = "Radio" Name ="vote' . $row . '" value= "pacada"></td>';
    ...
```

That way all rows will have different names.

Comment: Thanks,it worked. However, some radio buttons[8 undecided buttons] which are supposed to be checked, are unchecked. And if I try to check the undecided button, another radio button from another row will be unchecked. What do you think is the error? Thanks again.

Comment: Hard to say...Check the html-source to make sure you have the same names on each element as youe expect.